# Dataframe object has no attribute

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

My code below takes a weekly average of numbers

```
df = information.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).mean('numbers')
```

When I print the head of this it works

```
   date      numbers
xx/xx/xxxx     4
xx/xx/xxxx     6
...
```

However I want to print this as a line plot

```
plt.plot(df.date, df.numbers, data = df)
```

And get the error

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'
```

I realise now that when I do df.columns, I get

```
Index(['numbers'], dtype='object')
```

Can someone explain whats happening here, and how I amend this so that both date and numbers is part of the dataframe.

Comment: Are you sure 'date' is a column and not the index?

Comment: try printing the information using df.info(). It will give all the information like column names and their data type as well from there you can pick the correct column name.

Comment: `df = information.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="W"), as_index=False).mean("numbers")` ? To prevent the `date` field becoming the index.